# Scientific library in C/C with OpenMP

Tags: openmp

I have to exploit PpenMP in some algorithm and for this purpose I need some mathematical functions, like `eig` or `svd` as it is available in MATLAB and it is quite fast in MATLAB. I already tried the following libraries with OpenMP

1. [GSL - GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)
2. [Eigen C++ template library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)

but I don't know why my OpenMP parallelised code is much slower than the serial code, may be there is some thing wrong in the library, or that the function `random`, `eig` or `svd` are blocking? I have no idea how to figure it out, can some body suggest me which is most compatible math library with OpenMP.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend Intel's [MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl/); note that it costs money which may affect your decision.  I neither know nor care what language(s) it is written in, just so long as it provides APIs callable from my chosen language.  Mine is Fortran, but it has bindings for C too

If you look around SO you'll find many questions from people whose first (or second or third) OpenMP programs were actually slower than their serial versions.  Look at some of the answers.  Don't conclude that there is a magic bullet, in the shape of a library, to make your code faster.  Instead, realise that it is most likely that you've written a poorly-parallelised program and fix that.

Finally, if you have an installation of Matlab, don't expect to be able to write your own routines to outperform Matlab's.  I won't say it can't be done, but I think you'll find it very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

GSL is compatible with OpenMP. You can try with Intel Math Kernel Library which comes as a trial version for free.
If the speed up is not so much, then probably the code is not much parallelizable. You may want to debug and see the details of the running threads in Intel Thread Checker, that could be helpful to see where the bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to find a fast implementation of lapack (or related routines) which is already threaded, but it's a little hard to tell from your question.   High Performance Mark suggests MKL, which is an excellent example; others include [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) or [FLAME](http://z.cs.utexas.edu/wiki/flame.wiki/FrontPage) which are open source but take some doing to build.